# Quicksort partition algorithm -- why is the swap with the pivot value outside of the loop?

Tags: language-agnostic, quicksort, clrs

I was looking at the quick sort algorithm in CLRS's Introduction to Algorithms https://dl.ebooksworld.ir/books/Introduction.to.Algorithms.4th.Leiserson.Stein.Rivest.Cormen.MIT.Press.9780262046305.EBooksWorld.ir.pdf

On pg 184, it shows the partition algorithm, pasted below for convenience:

[image]

It's been many years since I've looked at this, but now I don't understand why we need line 7 as opposed to make the loop go from `j = p` to `j = r`, and `return i`. Is there some performance improvement to doing it as shown in the picture?

Comment: It saves one (data) comparison: if that extra iteration would be made, the `if` condition is evaluated, but it is already sure what its outcome is, so an unnecessary one.